# Create event by coding

Tags: c#, .net

I have a checkedListBox and a panel. They are both created by code. Now I want to make an event that by checking and Unchecking an item of the checkedListBox items this panel gets enabled or disable. I have the following code but It doesn't work and throws exception on run time.

```
CheckedListBox chlb = new CheckedListBox();
for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count(); i++)
{
    chlb.Items.Add( dr[i]["Value_Name"].ToString());
    if ((bool)dr[i]["HasText"] == true)
    {
        Panel pnltxt = new Panel();
        pnltxt.Size = new Size(630, 30);
        chlb.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, argx) => pnltxt.Enabled =
           (chlb.GetItemCheckState(i).ToString().Trim() == "Unchecked" ? false : true);
    }
}
```

Error message is:

> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'.
>   +       chlb.GetItemCheckState(i)   'chlb.GetItemCheckState(i)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' System.Windows.Forms.CheckState {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

Can you please help me how to write the correct code for this event.

Comment: Let me guess, `dr.Count()` is `7`?

Comment: This isn't breaking anything, but you really shouldn't be comparing against "Unchecked" as a string. Just compare against CheckedState.Unchecked, and avoid the string problem.

Comment: For the love of clarity, change `chlb.GetItemCheckState(i).ToString().Trim() == "Unchecked" ? false : true` to `chlb.GetItemCheckState(i) != CheckState.Unchecked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with lambda expressions and closure.

When you create a lambda expression (as you do with your event handler) and it references an outside variable, the compiler needs to create a closure to include that variable so that you lambda function can use it. So here:

```
for (int i=0; ......)
{
     //...
     chlb.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, argx) => pnltxt.Enabled =
         (chlb.GetItemCheckState(i).ToString().Trim() == "Unchecked" ? false : true);
     //..........................^
}
```

The lambda expression uses `i` which is the loop variable, it has to have a closure that includes it so it can use it when the function is executed. But here's the problem, it doesn't get a *copy* of the variable at the time the lambda expression was assigned to your event handler, it actually has a reference to the *same* variable as the one you are looping on. So what's the problem? When you execute the lambda expression (i.e. the event happens) the value of `i` is the value it had at the end of the loop! Which is, `dr.Count()` (presumably, `7`).

The solution is to copy the variable inside you loop (as in @astander's answer) so that it will close over the copy of the variable that will retain the value it had *when you attached the event handler*.

So:

```
for (int i=0; ......)
{
     int copyOfi = i;    // A new variable will get created every iteration!
     //...
     chlb.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, argx) => pnltxt.Enabled =
         (chlb.GetItemCheckState(copyOfi).ToString().Trim() == "Unchecked" ? false : true);
     //..........................^
     // And this will close to include only the `copyOfi` we created in this iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
if ((bool)dr[i]["HasText"]) {
    Panel pnltxt = new Panel();
    pnltxt.Size = new Size(630, 30);
    int index = i;
    chlb.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, argx) => pnltxt.Enabled =
        chlb.GetItemCheckState(index).ToString().Trim() != "Unchecked";
}
```

It is something that is called *Access to modified closure* , and has to do with the scopingrules of closures.

Have a look at [Access to modified closure](http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/access-to-modified-closure/)

> This message is stating that the variable you are using from your
>   enumeration may potentially change and not be what you would expect it
>   to be at the time it will be used.  This will not throw a compiler
>   error .
>
> The recommended approach when using variables like this inside an
>   enumeration (for each loop) is to create a local copy and use that.

So accordingly, I created a local copy of the variable `i` in `index` and used that.

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why that change is important.  This post, without an explanation, is a low quality answer.

Comment: @Servy, I am looking for a decent link/article to provide to the OP

Comment: It is not considered appropriate on this site to just link to a solution to a problem.  Your answer should *answer the question* not just link to an answer elsewhere.

Comment: @Servy, I have updated the answer as to your request.

Comment: I have edited the answer and simplifyed the part `pnltxt.Enabled =
(condition ? false : true)` and chaned it to `pnltxt.Enabled =
!condition` and also removed the `== true` part.